# String is not assigned in a while loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm reading a file from a FTP server, and I'm trying to use a `while` loop to assign the next line to a `String` and check if it's not null (`Nothing`).
The issue is that I'm pretty much used to `C#`, and this is my first attempt at `VB`. Can you tell me if I did something wrong that's causing it?

```
Dim request As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim url As String = "ftp://ftp.harelwebs.net/" + "Default.aspx"
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASS")
Try
    Dim stream As IO.Stream = request.OpenRead(url)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    While (stream.CanRead And (line = sr.ReadLine()) <> Nothing)
        MessageBox.Show(line)
    End While
    stream.Close()
    sr.Close()
Catch ex As WebException
    MessageBox.Show("Error.. " + ex.Message)
```

I've tested the same code in `C#` and it works perfectly, I have no idea why it doesn't work in `VB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot assign a value in VB.NET inside a test clause. The reason being that `=` is used for both assignment and comparison and it would be very confusing and ambiguous in cases.

The solution to your problem would simply be to do this:

```
Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
While (stream.CanRead And line <> Nothing)
    MessageBox.Show(line)
    line = sr.ReadLine()
End While
```

If necessary you could wrap the assignment in an if statement if there may be instances where you want to set the `line` value to `Nothing` to prevent the loop running.